# How can I find out a DirectShow filter's clsid?

Tags: c++, directshow

I want to use the LAV Decoder filter in my application, but i can't figure out the clsid.

Where do I find it? Is there a header file i can include?

Do I have to insert the clsid guid manually?

Comment: LAV is open source, you can simply look in the .h file.  Like LAVVideo.h, EE30215D-164F-4A92-A4EB-9D4C13390F9F

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's better to hard code the GUIDs in your code. 
You can find out all DirectShow filter GUID with [GraphStudioNext](https://code.google.com/p/graph-studio-next/) (a replacement for GraphEdit).